# Plotly Choropleth (python) background color?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Is there a way to change the background color of Plotly's choropleth figures?

```py
data = go.Choropleth(
    locations=region_poll.Abb,
    locationmode='USA-states',
    z=region_poll['3_ma']
)

layout = go.Layout(
    title_text='United States Map',
    geo=dict(
        scope='usa',
        showlakes=False
    ),
    paper_bgcolor='#F2F2F2',
    plot_bgcolor='#F2F2F2'
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
```

Currently the paper_bgcolor and plot_bgcolor are turning everything to the correct background color, except for a rectangle around the map, which remains white.